# Importing file to Alfresco programatically (through java backed webscript)

Tags: java, pdf, import, alfresco

I am having problem when importing document (PDF) into Alfresco repository inside java backed webscript. I am using writer of ContentService. 
If I use

```
ContentWriter writer = ContentService.getWriter(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
writer.setEncoding("UTF-8");
writer.setMimetype("application/pdf");
writer.putContent(new String(byte []) );
```

or

```
writer.putContent(new String(byte [], "UTF-8") );
```

my document is not previewable (I see blank PDF file, tried with few small PDF files, don't know what would happen in case of other/larger files). 
But if I use another `putContent` method which takes File as argument I'll successfully import the document.

```
writer.setEncoding("UTF-8");
writer.setMimetype("application/pdf");
writer.putContent(File);
```

I don't want to import file from disk since I get the file as Base64 encoded String but I don't know what am I missing.

Comment: is that your code? writer.putContent(new String(byte []) );
maybe you could try putContent with an InputStream...
What are you doing with the "Base64 encoded String"?

Comment: Sorry I tried to omit variable name, I'll edit the question to make it more clear. TBH I didn't tried to use InputStream as argument, I'll try. I decode the stream using Apache Base64.decodeBase64(). It goes well since I use that output to generate file (used for import in second scenario I wrote in question).

Comment: Nice noticing Meiko, it gets in repostiory just fine when using InputStream as an argument. I sure don't know what went wrong when creating a string from byte array. Thanks a lot. Please write an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an `InputStream` as a parameter for `ContentWriter::putContent`. So you will prevent the String to byte array (and vice versa) conversions, which leads to difficulties with the encoding.

```
writer.putContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64("yourBase64EncodedString")))
```